# Hibernate 5 Legacy bootstrap JTA JtaTransactionFactory (BMT) Auto Flushing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We have migrated a legacy application from hibernate 4.3.10.Final to 5.2.10.Final including spring version to 4.3.10.RELEASE.

We have then changed the following configuration.

Spring context:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
```

to

Spring context:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">JBossAS</property>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jta</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
<!-- BMT. Default is false see org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings#PREFER_USER_TRANSACTION. -->
<property name="hibernate.jta.prefer_user_transaction">true</property>
```

However, the application doesn't behave as it did in hibernate 4.3 as it seems that the application is auto flushing and behaving as CMT would.

Here is a scenario. In the simpliest form.

```
@Transactional()
ObjectA.assemble(...)
ObjectA objectA = new ObjectA();
ObjectB objectB = objectBAssemblerImpl.assemble(...); /* objectBAssemblerImpl.assemble doesn't contain the @Transactional annotation. */
hibernate.saveorupdate(objectB);
objectA.setObjectB(objectB);
Objectc objectC = hibernate.findById(ObjectC.class, 4);
objectA.setObjectC(objectC);
objectA.set...()
```

When line hibernate.findById() is executed, hibernate performs a flush however when the same sceanrio is done within hibernate 4.3 it doesn't.

Can someone help to determine how JTA BMT should be configired in hibernate 5 / Spring 4.3 using hibernate's legacy bootstrap? Have i missed something?

Comment: Ofcourse it will do a `flush` as that is needed to have consistent query results... A `flush` isn't a `commit`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand a 'flush' isn't a 'commit'. Within hibernate 4.3 JTA BMT, a 'flush' would occur just before the 'commit' unless manually flushed. Within hibernate 4.3 JTA CMT, a 'flush' would be automatic as observed above. Due to the legacy code we want the 'flush' to occur as per hibernate 4.3. Our db  insert triggers expect all the fields to be populated within an insert. We do not want an insert and then an update to include the other fields. This will cause issues for us.